# node, express, jade: How to create select options from a hash

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've just started to play around with node, express and thus, jade. I try to do something like this in a jade template:

```
my-options = {"this": "something", "that": "something else", "those": "more stuff", "these": "also included"}

form
  select(name="myselection")
    each option, key in my-options
      option(value="#{key}") option
```

However, all I get is an 500 server error which is not helpfull at all. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**
I've just figured out, that jade templates themselves cannot contain variable definitions. Thus, the `my_options` hash needs to be defined in the corresponding router.js file and passed as an parameter to the appropriate `result.render()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line must be executable JS code and 'my-options' is not a valid JS variable name.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSz, so I changed this line to `var my_options = ...`. But I still get those errors

Comment: Also:   option(value="#{key}") #{option}

Comment: Thnx again. To my regret, that does not seem to be the solution.

Comment: I have run this successfully on Express 3.2.5 and the latest jade: `var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var port = 3000;
app.set("port", port);
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.get("/test", function (req, res) {
  res.render('jadeSelect');
});

app.listen(port);` with jade file `my_options = {"this": "something", "that": "something else", "those": "more stuff", "these": "also included"}

form
    select(name="myselection")
        each option, key in my_options
            option(value="#{key}") #{option}`

Comment: Cheers John! I think the key is, not to use line breaks for formatting the variable code as I did. Just as @iheartramen suggests, multi-line declarations might not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can define variables in Jade, you just have to start the line with a hyphen.  A `-` at the start of a line tells Jade to execute the code that follows without outputting it.  A `=` at the start of a line tells Jade to execute the code that follows and output it after it's done.

So for example if you do

```
- var foo = "bar"
= 2+2
p #{foo}
```

you will see this in your page source:

```
4
<p>bar</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, too!
I've read about this possibility with variables in jade. However, when I tested this with slightly more complex variable constructs, which I stretched over a view lines for readability reasons, I couldn't make it work (added a hyphen to each line)...

Comment: Can you give an example of a more complex variable construct that wouldn't work?

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to declare some associate array like structure, such as

`- var my_options = {key1: "value1",
-                  key2: "value2",
-                  ...
-                  keyX: "valueX"};`

D*mn, it doesn't show the newlines here in the comment section... So each key value pair sits on a new line for readability reasons.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean.  Yeah, darn Jade just doesn't support multi-line declarations.